# Use Local JSON file in Unit Test

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xctest

I have an app called "FFQuestions".  I use a local json file called `QA.json`.

Is there any way I can **use `QA.json` in my "FFQuestionsTests" folder files** without recreating the file and dropping it in that folder?  Is it something I need to change with my code to get to it? Or is it something as simple as adding the Target Membership for "FFQuestionsTests"?

*This is my method for loading `QA.json`...*

```
func loadJSONFromFile() -> [String: Any]? {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "QA", withExtension: "json") else {return nil}
    guard let data: Data = NSData(contentsOf: url) as Data? else {return nil}

    do {
        let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
        guard let dictionary = object as? [String: Any] else {return nil}
        return dictionary
    } catch  {
        print("Not parsed")
    }

    return nil
}
```

*even thought it might need to be done somewhat differently in Unit Test so I tried out...*

```
func loadJSONFromTestsFile() -> [String: Any]? {
    let testBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let url = testBundle.url(forResource: "QA", withExtension: "json")

    guard let data: Data = NSData(contentsOf: url!) as Data? else {return nil}

    do {
        let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
        guard let dictionary = object as? [String: Any] else {return nil}
        print(dictionary)
        return dictionary
    } catch  {
        print("Not parsed")
    }

    return nil
}
```

So that is what I've tried, but I'm still getting a `nil` crash.

Comment: Where exactly do you have this `nil` crash? Which line? What error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was something as simple as adding the Target Membership for "FFQuestionsTests"

Comment: Is the code that worked for the unit test, the first or the second one? What does Membership for FFQuestionsTest mean? In the Question, FFQuestionsTest is said to be a folder, not a file.

Comment: @Efren the code is the first and the second, all that mattered was I checked the box adding Target Membership.  Pretty easy!

Comment: I could only make a unit test work, similar to the second code, the first only works with App code. My question was about the Target you say you check, if it can only be done on files and not folders as mentioned in the post, FFQuestionsTests is a folder. Maybe update the question to clarify.